# Actual NetBeans build folder: `build` or `nbbuild`?

Tags: netbeans

Do recent versions of NetBeans use a `build` directory or an `nbbuild` directory; or both?

I see a lot of `.gitignore` files implying that NetBeans creates and uses a `build` directory. These same `.gitignore` files imply that NetBeans also uses a `nbbuild` directory (which would make more sense and be more polite by reducing the risk of name clashes.).

I'm wondering if maybe nowadays NetBeans uses an `nbbuild` directory exclusively, and the `build` directory is something ancient, before they had the wisdom of switching to `nbbuild`. Is `build` a directory NetBeans still uses, or is that something legacy and abandoned?

Comment: I think it would have been good to clarify that you are talking about Netbeans project codebase  -  when I first reviewed the question I was thinking from a Netbeans user perspective as opposed to Netbeans project developer/maintainer perspective

Comment: I am referring to NetBeans from a user perspective. If you download the latest version of NetBeans as a user and build a project, are there any circumstances or configurations in which NetBeans would create a `build` directory? It's as simple as that. The expected answer is either "no, NetBeans no longer creates a `build` directory when building any project"; or "yes, NetBeans still creates a `build` directory under the following circumstances: …".

Comment: Yes, from a user perspective, when you "create a new project", the wizard starts by asking which build tool your project will use. The wizard however does not include git as a VCS by default - not with a vanilla installation anyway.  
I could choose between ant/maven/gradle which will utilise a `build` directory.

Comment: That sounds like we're getting closer to an answer, but your answer isn't clear. Are you saying that the Ant, Maven, and Gradle build types _all three_ would result in a `build` directory being created? I was told by someone else that the Maven build type would _not_ create a `build` directory. So could you double-check that?

Comment: Yes, I have managed to reproduce a project using the wizard that includes an nbbuild dir, I think I have a more definitive answer - will update my answer.  Though  the `.gitignore` file is not generated by default - so these users must be  adding those directories in .gitignore manually (or have a VCS plugin). In short, the answer is yes, such a `build` dir is inclulded and it is due to the defaults of the underlying build tools - in this case ant, and the build.properties has `build` as the default setting for the build.dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NETBEANS USER PERSPECTIVE**

When using the project wizard to start a project, one is faced with the option of choosing between 3 build tools namely, ant, maven and gradle.  When choosing ant as the build tool, and create a `Java Application`  it will include an `nbbuild` folder which houses all the files describing the build setup/configuration.  This is only true for an `ant` based Java Application (not gradle/maven).

The default for `build.dir` in the  `project.properties` file is `build` , and so when building the project it will output built files into `build/*`

So yes both `nbbuild` and `build` are used under these circumstances. With a vanilla installation of Netbeans, no VCS is included and hence `.gitignore` must be manually populated.

**NETBEANS SOURCE PROJECT** (keeping as historical/additional information)

There is at least 1 target that utilises a build directory.

https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/master/nbbuild/build.xml#L1844C23-L1844C23

The `test.dist.dir` is set to `build/testdist`

https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/master/nbbuild/build.properties#L19C15-L19C29

The purpose of `nbbuild` is to house all files related to building netbeans. The base build.xml imports from the `nbbuild/build.xml`

So yes, `build` directories are still generated inside Netbeans and should be ignored.

**SUMMARY**

`nbbuild` - used for housing files describing build configuration

`build` - used for compiled output files by underlying build tool

Comment: Please clarify: are these "targets" you are referring to related to building NetBeans itself? The question is not about building NetBeans, but about _using_ NetBeans to build projects.

Comment: This is about building the netbeans project codebase. My previous answer was from a user perspective - however when I created a  new project using the project wizard and gradle as the build tool choice, there were no traces of nbbuild inside my new project. Hence why I came to think you are talking about the project code base (from a developer/maintainer perspective), and why I deleted my previous answer.

Comment: This question is not about building the NetBeans project codebase. Note that the output directory used by NetBeans probably depends on what type of project you created (I'm guessing—I don't use NetBeans), so creating a Gradle project in some wizard may result in different types of directories being created. My guess is that originally NetBeans if creating a "bare" project would create a `build` directory, but I don't know—that's why I'm asking if NetBeans would create a `build` directory in _any_ circumstances.

Comment: I believe the answer is yes - and this has more to do with the underlying build tool being used (1 needs to be chosen, and the choice is between ant/gradle/maven within the wizard).

Comment: @GarretWilson Let me know if more clarity is required on anything

Comment: "The default for `build.dir` in the `project.properties` file is `build`,  , and so when building the project it will output built files into `build/*`" Are you referring specifically and only to the Ant build type, or for all the build types? "So yes both `nbbuild` and `build` are used under these circumstances." It's still not clear what "these circumstances" refer to. All of the above circumstances (Ant, Maven, and Gradle), or only for Ant projects?

Comment: "Are you referring specifically and only to the Ant build" , yes, nbbuild is only generated with ant as the build tool.  "these circumstances"  , I mean when using the default ant project that was generated with nbbuiild directory - i.e when not changing project.properties to change `build.dir` value

Comment: I appreciate your work on this. Let me give you a tip on composition: you might consider directly and concisely answering the question, and _then_ filling in the details. For example, "By default NetBeans creates an `nbuild` directory for project settings and a `build` folder for build output _only_ if a project is configured as an Ant project—and even then the `build` directory is configurable." After that you can go into your explanation of tests, the different build types (which do _not_ use a `build` directory), etc. I hope this writing tip is helpful. Thanks again for research and answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @GarretWilson, I will bear this in mind. And thank you for your patience/interaction which got us this far in answering your question. It was interesting to look into as an ex-Java developer (not used for 8 years or so, might use it again someday though), and Netbeans having been my first Java IDE some 17 years ago at school